# Can I use Engineering Meta SE for a Sandbox?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions, question-quality, moderators

I have problems writing a good question here and don't want to risk getting banned for another 6 months or more. Is there a way that I can Sandbox here like in Worldbulding.SE?

https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, please don't.  Meta is meant to address issues related to the site.  It is not a sandbox.

Chat *might* be an alternative to use as a sandbox, but it's not very active and the formatting doesn't really work well there.

One thing that may help you though, is to dissuade yourself of the notion that other SE sites are like WorldBuilding.  WB is the exception to SE sites with radically different expectations regarding quality.  If you look at a question and say "this would be a good question on WB" then it's likely a very poor fit for Engineering.